# React issue with updating state during re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components, a StaticComponent and an InteractiveComponent. The StaticComponent shows the user's information. It has a link to edit the
information. That link has an onClick that fires off the `handleEditClick` function. This replaces the StaticComponent with an InteractiveComponent which has a form.

```
var StaticComponent = React.createClass({
  handleEditClick: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    React.render(<InteractiveComponent user_info={this.props.user_info}  
                                       form_status={'form-to-be-sent'} />, 
                  document);
  },
})
```

The InteractiveComponent sets the state of the user_info from the props. It also 
assigns the state's `formSubmissionStatus` value to be 'form-to-be-sent' for the 
initial state, again from the props. The component also has a handleSubmit function and obviously the render function.

```
var InteractiveComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      user_info: JSON.parse(this.props.user_info),
      formSubmissionStatus: this.props.form_status
    };
  },

  handleSubmit: function(event, data) {
    // ...
  },

  render: function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

The render function has a form that calls `handleSubmit` on submit. It also assigns a `userInfo` that will set the new props to be either the existing user_info data in the props, or the updated info from the state, depending on the submission status of the form.

The render function also renders either the form, if the status is set to 'form-to-be-sent', or it will render a StaticComponent otherwise. That's because it assumes the form was submitted.

```
render: function () {
  var profileForm = (
      <form ref="form" onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
        <label>Your Name</label>
        <textarea id="user_name" defaultValue={this.state.user_info.name} ref='name' />
        <button className='greenbutton' type="submit">Update</button>
      </form>
    );

  var userInfo = this.state.formSubmissionStatus == 'form-to-be-sent' ? this.props.user_info : JSON.stringify(this.state.user_info);

  return (
    this.state.formSubmissionStatus == 'form-to-be-sent' ? profileForm : <StaticComponent user_info={userInfo} />
  );
}
```

The handleSubmit updates the user info in a new associative array, and does an ajax POST submission to the server. Before the ajax call, it updates the state of the user info to the latest data, and updates the formSubmissionStatus value.

```
handleSubmit: function(event, data) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this.refs.form.getDOMNode()).serialize(),
        latestUserInfo = JSON.parse(this.props.user_info),
        name = this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value.trim(),
        that = this;

    latestUserInfo['name'] = name;

    $.ajax({
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'form-submit',
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function() {
        that.setState({
          user_info: latestUserInfo,
          formSubmissionStatus: 'form-already-submitted'
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the formSubmissionStatus value doesn't seem to be updated properly in the handleSubmit. I can click edit, fill in the form, press submit and see the new data update on the server, and the new info in a new StaticComponent. But I can't seem to be able to load the form up again by clicking on edit the second time. Using webdev tools, it seems as those the setState in the `beforeSend` callback isn't properly updating the formSubmissionStatus status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second time you click edit, and React renders an interactive component, it sees that there is already an existing InteractiveComponent there, so it reuses it by updating it's props and rerendering.

In your example, updating it's props and rerendering does nothing to change it's state. There is a component lifecycle method for `componentWillReceiveProps` that gives you an opportunity to transfer the new `Props` to the state.

So, try something like this on your `interactiveComponent`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.setState({user_info: nextProps.user_info, formSubmissionStatus: nextProps.form_status});
}
```

Comment: +1; an even better solution would be to remove the `React.render` call from inside `StaticComponent`, and to instead make both `StaticComponent` and `InteractiveComponent` a child of some parent component that decides when to render each.

Comment: Agree.  That is a cleaner architecture, and more of the way that React intends for it's components to work together.